# How do update record if count of totalrecord greater than 50 in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have 2 tables in PostgreSQL. I have to fetch total records from both tables. If `count >50`then update status=5 of oldest record .Here is query for oldest record. I have to update oldest record in single query.
here is query I have tried to find oldest record

```
(
  select 'SPORTS' AS eventType,
         activity.articleId,
         activity.title,
         activity.articleText,
         activity.createdDate,
         activity.creatorscreenname as creatorScreenNameStr  
  FROM SPORTS activity 
  where activity.status=1  
    and activity.createdBy=101 
  order by createdDate ASC 
  limit 1
) 
UNION  
(
  select 'MUSIC' AS musicType,
          activity.wikiTopicId as articleId,
          activity.title as title,
          activity.problemDescription as articleText,
          activity.createdDate,
          activity.creatorScreenName as creatorScreenNameStr   
  FROM MUSIC activity 
  where activity.status=1  
    and activity.createdBy=101 
  order by createdDate ASC limit 1
)  
ORDER BY 5 ASC 
limit 1
```

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Postgresql? Don't tag products not involved.

Comment: Why are you aliasing the tables? `UNION` doesn’t require it.

Comment: I am not sure I understand. You want to count the records in both tables. When the total is greater than 50 (e.g. 30 records each = 60), then you want to update the status of the oldest record (that can reside in one table or the other) to 5. Otherwise you want to do nothing. Is this correct?

Comment: what's the pk?.. to update by?..

Comment: @VaoTsun articleId is primary key

Comment: @ThorstenKettner yes , count 50 = (Music+sports)

Comment: you will have 4 cte (one for you set and 3 to update)to have it in one statement...

Comment: @VaoTsun have no idea about CTE , will implements anything which work.

Comment: ...with a as (select union) update from a, left outer join a where ... returning... no, it won't work... to weird, sorry

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143186/discussion-between-glen-maxwell-and-vao-tsun).

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know you cannot update either one table or another with one statement. So keep it simple and write two:

```
update sports
set status = 5
where (select count(*) from sports) + (select count(*) from music) > 50
and createddate = (select min(createddate) from sports)
and not exists (select * from music m where m.createddate < sports.createddate);
```

and

```
update music
set status = 5
where (select count(*) from music) + (select count(*) from sports) > 50
and createddate = (select min(createddate) from music)
and not exists (select * from sports s where s.createddate < music.createddate);
```

There may be some way to do this more eloquently, but it's easy to unterstand I think: update the record where the date is the minimum date and there is no even older date in the other table.